# Wordpress and Accordions, nothing works now

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am quite stumped.  I am not sure what I could have done to break the accordion function in either the Accordion Shortcode plugin nor the CSS Accordion code I just tried.  Mostly I need to understand how to troubleshoot these so I am throwing my self at your mercy so I can help get this site back to proper functionality.

First, the page with the Accordion Shortcode: http://londoncapital.biz/partners/global/

I was using Symple Shortcode plugin till I had to reinstall the site then that plugin stopped working.  I suspect this was related to the WP3.7.1 upgrade but I cannot be sure.  So I decided to just find another plugin that did work and the Accordion Plugin worked and looked better for the site so I was happy.  At some point, while going through and fixing some of the oddball issues that popped up after the reinstall (weird spaces that somehow were being generated from the restored backup) and the Better WP Security plugin being overzealous in its protection, I was happy with the Accordion Shortcode plugin.  Then...it stopped working.  Because I could not track down what I had possibly done I decided to look into an alternative accordion and found a CSS version.  Thought that was perfect and would get away from any plugin incompatibility but alas this too has failed.  It currently collapsed and it will not expand.

CSS Accordion page: londoncapital.  biz /test-home

I followed this site: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/ and referenced the CSS file like so:

```
@import url("../onyx/accordion.css");
```

I suspect there is a simple answer but damned if I can figure it out.  Thank you for any efforts in advance!
This file is sitting in the same directory as the normal style.css (style4.css for this template to be exact).

Comment: Your sections are missing the IDs for the anchors to actually target. E.g.

        `<a href="#about">About</a>`

requires a corresponding

        `<section id="#about">...</section>`

in order to work

Comment: Also, be aware that the `:target` selector used by that technique [is not supported by IE6-9](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) and you may want to consider either using a HTML5 shim/shiv to add support for the `<section>` elements, or swap them out in favour of `<div>`

Comment: Ah, I figured it was something stupidly simple.  Guess that's what happens when your brain has been beaten up badly when dealing the other issues surrounding this site.  Thanks guys!

Comment: @Dre - would a direct swap for '<section>' to '<div>' be as simple as that?

Comment: Either swap them out for `<div class="section">` or use a [HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to polyfill support for it

Comment: @Dre Deciding not to take a chance on a 'working' page, I setup a test page and tried the section/div swap and it kinda does something but not overly useful.  http://londoncapital.biz/test-home/

Comment: I see the problem, answer posted below

Answer (score 0):

Your Section ID's are missing as required to trigger the target.Though you added ID's to Anchor tag.
Demo : `<section id="#about">...</section>` http://jsfiddle.net/dhanith/7y7mY/

Comment: While that is a good observation, and does help to make sure the coding is proper, it did not solve the issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment above: you've solved one problem by adding the IDs, but there's now another problem. You've swapped the `sections` in the HTML for `div`, but you haven't changed the CSS to match. Change all the instances of `.accordion section` to `.accordion div` like so:

```
.accordion section:target { ... }
.accordion section:target:hover { ... }
.accordion section:target h2 { ... }
.accordion section:target h2 a { ...}
```

to 
    .accordion div:target { ... }
    .accordion div:target:hover { ... }
    .accordion div:target h2 { ... }
    .accordion div:target h2 a { ...}

You'll also need to do the same for `.horizontal section` and `.vertical section`. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabW2/1/) to see it in action

Comment: Hmm, I replaced all instances of 'section' with 'div' but that seemed to do nothing.  I tried the css you used in JSFiddle and that worked.  How odd.  My brain is too tired to do a direct comparision atm, so I'll just say thanks and see if I can get it to work on the main problem page now.